# delete single cron job by PHP (curl)

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have created some cron jobs using curl:

```
curl -s  https://ex.example.com/cron/test1.php
curl -s  https://ex.example.com/cron/test2.php
curl -s  https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php
curl -s  https://ex.example.com/cron/test4.php
```

Now I want to delete a single cron job using PHP:

```
curl -s https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The method you'd use to delete a cron job in PHP would be determined by how the cron job is set up in your system.

Comment: I have used this code to add new cron 
exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n curl -s https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php " | crontab -', $output);

I want to delete only one

Comment: Your link is inaccessible, at least to me. Good practice on Stack Overflow is to paste your code in the question itself and format it.

Comment: Also, your post should have a clear and concise question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's crontab is just a text file.  When you run `crontab -e`, a copy of the crontab from `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` is copied to `/tmp`, then opened with a text editor.  Once saved, if changes are made, the temp file is copied back to the crontabs directory to overwrite the user's previous crontab (if it exists).

The `crontab` command allows you to list the contents, or launch it for manual editing, but doesn't specifically allow you to add (though you've created a wrapper for it) or delete from this file.  I would write a wrapper that would do that for you, which would take two command line parameters:

- Something that specifies what you want to do; add or remove.
- The line that you want to add or remove.

It would look something like this:

**crontab.php**

```
$cron   = '/var/spool/cron/crontabs/' . `echo $USER`;
$action = $argv[1];
$line   = array_slice( $argv, 2 );

if ( $action == 'add' ) {
    file_put_contents( $cron, $line . "\n", FILE_APPEND );
} elseif ( $action == 'del' ) {
    $file = explode( "\n", file_get_contents( $cron ));
    unlink( $cron );

    foreach ( $file as $file_line ) {
        if ( trim( $file_line ) != trim( $line )) {
            file_put_contents( $cron, $file_line . "\n", FILE_APPEND );
        }
    }
}
```

You could run it like this:

```
./crontab.php add * * * * curl -s https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php
```

Which would add the line:

```
* * * * curl -s https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php
```

...to the end of the user's crontab.  The following:

```
./crontab.php add * * * * curl -s https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php
```

...would be used to delete that line, no matter where it is in the file.

Note that the above script is just a sample to get you started in a direction.  It's missing a few things, namely error-checking:

- It doesn't verify that the user's crontab exists.  If the user has never added a cron job, then the file won't exist.  You'll need to check that it's there, and create a new file if it doesn't.
- It doesn't verify the parameters that were set.  For instance, that the first parameter is either "add" or "del", or that the second parameter exists.  You should verify that not only the first parameter is set, but that it is a valid option, and spit out a usage summary if it's not.  For extra credit, you can check that the second parameter not only exists, but is a valid cron format.
- You might want to add some output to tell the user that their job was successfully added or deleted.  Additionally, if they specify a job to delete that doesn't exist, it might be a good idea to tell them that too so that they don't think something was deleted when it wasn't because it was never actually there.

Answer (score 0):

use file_get_contents to get the file into a string, use str_replace to remove the line, and use file_put_contents to save it.  like

```
<?php 
$file="/path/to/jobs.sh";
$jobs=file_get_contents($file);
$jobs=str_replace('curl -s https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php','',$jobs,$count);
if($count<1){
    echo "failed to delete the job, couldn't find it!";
    return 1;
}else{
    file_put_contents($file,$str);
    echo 'deleted '.$count.' jobs!';
}
```

- 1 annoyance with this approach is that it leaves a stray newline every time it deletes a job. if you don't want that, keep in mind that if you're deleting the first job, it might not start with a line, and if you're deleting the last job, it might not end with a newline, with that in mind, it's probably easiest to use a regex, like `preg_replace('/\s*'.preg_quote('curl -s https://ex.example.com/cron/test3.php','/').'\s*/',"\n",$jobs,$count);` - that will not leave stray newlines behind, and will account for the possibility of the job neither starting with, nor ending with, a newline, but remove the newline in all 4 cases. (case 1: it doesn't start with a newline, and it doesn't end with a newline, it's the only job. case 2: it doesn't start with a newline, but ends with 1. case 3: it starts with a newline, but doesn't end with 1. case 4: it starts with a newline, and ends with a newline) - if you want to do this with str_replace, you would have to call it 4 times! (and in the correct order)